# java qt server/client dta transfer

Tags: java, qt, client-server, transfer

I created  a  client  (created by JAVA) and a server (by qt/c++), but  I have a data transfer  problem (something wrong with format I think).

The server side code:

```
void Pirate::DateArrived()
{
QTcpSocket *socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket *>(sender());  
QDataStream in (socket);
qDebug()<< socket->bytesAvailable();// here it give me the number of chars i sent in this ex:3
QString cmd ;
in >> cmd;
qDebug()<< cmd.size(); // here it always stay 0
qDebug() << cmd; // always ""

}
public void SendData(String data) throws IOException
    {
        OutputStream theOutput = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(theOutput);
        out.write("abc");
        out.flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html), when you deserialize a `QString`, it is expected that the data will consist of the string length in bytes (quint32) followed by the data in UTF-16.

Comment: thank you that was very helpful and if someone have the same problem just switch QDataStream to QTextStream and thanks again